# Oracle Reference Partition - How to make sure I'm getting the benefits when I select

Tags: oracle, select, partition

I'm trying to make sure I'm getting the benefit of selecting from a partition when using reference partitions.

In normal partitions, I know you have to include the column(s) on which the partition is defined in order for Oracle to know it can just search one specific partition.

My question is, when I'm selecting from a reference-partitioned table, do I just need to include the column on which the reference foreign key is defined?  Or do I need to join and include the parent table's column on which the partition is actually defined?

```
create table alpha (
    name varchar2(240) not null,
    partition_no number(14) not null,
    constraint alpha_pk
        primary key (name),
    constraint alpha_c01
        check (partition_no > 0)
)
    partition by range(partition_no)
    interval (1)
    (partition empty values less than (1))
;

create table beta (
    name varchar2(240) not null,
    alpha_name varchar2(240) not null,
    some_data number not null,
    constraint beta_pk
        primary key (name),
    constraint beta_f01
        foreign key (alpha_name)
        references alpha (name)
)
    partition by reference (beta_f01)
;
```

Assume the tables in production will have much more data in them, with hundreds of millions of rows in the beta table, but merely thousands per partition.

Is this all I need?

```
select b.some_data
    from beta b
    where b.alpha_name = 'Blah'
;
```

Thanks if anyone can verify this for me.  Or can explain anything else I'm missing with regard to properly creating indexes in reference-partitioned tables.

[Edit] Removed part of the example where clause that shouldn't have been there.  The example is meant to represent reading the reference-partitioned with just the reference partition foreign key in the where clause.

Comment: Going by this - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-5E5BAB95-DE89-41CB-A61F-16A23A7A3B84.htm#VLDBG1280 - I do not think you will get benefit for any query on the child table alone.

Comment: I will need to verify, I don't think you need to specify the parent table. However, this is a bad example. All keys have global indexes and you are searching by PK, so there is no way Oracle will resort to partition pruning. It would simply use the keys. I can't think of an example where you specify enough to make pruning possible without specifying too much (i.e. making pruning unnecessary) without joining in the parent table. Can you?

Comment: What does the execution plan tell you?

Comment: Thanks folks.

@ewramner - I'm really not sure.  I guess I made the assumption that Oracle, when reading a table with hundreds of millions of rows, would automatically use a partition with less than 1,000 rows rather than using the global primary key.  Maybe all of this is unnecessary and based on a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: @Alex Poole - Not much.  I tried setting up some test cases, but didn't see anything in the Explain Plan, and wasn't even sure what to look for.  That's why I was hoping someone more knowledgeable than myself could enlighten me.

Comment: @ewramner I just realized I messed up my example.  I remember trying to avoid using the primary key, but I mistyped it.  I'm correcting the example to make it clearer.

Comment: @Alex Poole - Once I corrected the example and tried that, I saw "PARTITION REFERENCE SINGLE", so I'm feeling much more confident about my plan.

Comment: Thanks again to everyone who commented.